# JavaScript Local Folder Access

Tags: javascript

I am looking a functionality like follows for a web application,

User select a local folder with high resolution images.
Resize this images and send to server for processing.

Make folders in the local file system and copy the original high resolution images according to the server response

Can we achieve this without using any locally installed application but with a web application only. Please guide me, which method/technology can I start with.

Comment: Looks like you've tagged the question incorrectly: `google-chrome-app` is for [chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) which is **not a web application** and which can use [chrome.fileSystem API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem). For web apps this is not possible currently. In the [distant] future it'll be possible via [Native FileSystem API](https://github.com/WICG/native-file-system/blob/master/EXPLAINER.md).

Comment: Locally in a browser JavaScript cannot read the local file system, so you cannot read in the image and submit it to the server, if the server has access to the local file system then you could send the server the name of the file to process.

Comment: But I can read and submit the file to server if the user select the file through the file selection dialog.

Comment: That's the only way it can work. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will not allow to access local file system due to security reasons. Image any website able to play with local files. Browser provides sandbox where your js app can run.

You best options could be to use [webstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). You have limited capacity there though and it is not accessible directly to user. Different browsers can be varying implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with node.js and sharp or Imagemagick.

As others have mentioned in browser Javascript cannot access a local file system for security reasons. So you'd have to provide an upload interface to upload the image to a node server first, then you can convert the image into a buffer/data stream resize the buffer and save it again on the server ready to be downloaded.

NodeJs is a Javascript runtime
https://nodejs.org/en/

Express is a application framework you can build a webserver that can execute your javascript
https://expressjs.com/

(You've already said you'd prefer not to but) You could build it as an node desktop application using electron which would have access to the filesystem, but it would be a self contained app not a in browser application.
https://electronjs.org/

Sharp and imagemagick plugins are the most popular nodejs based image processors

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp

https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick

Hope this helps you get started

Comment: just thought I'd add a comment that aws lamba and s3 can do much of the heavy lifting for you so you don't need to configure servers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html